# How to programmatically publish/unpublished node using flag link and without using Rules?

Tags: flags

I have implemented the functionality on flag link click the content are unpublished and click on unflagging the content are published.
By using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

But this time I want to implement same functionality **without using rules** module and instead **using custom coding**.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any module may react to a piece of content being flagged by implementing `hook_flag()`. Here is the relevant do so:

```
mymodule_flag($action, $flag, $content_id, $account) {
  if ($action == 'flag') { // Or $action == 'unflag'.
    // Do something in response to the flagging.
  }

  if ($flag->name == 'yourflagname') {
    //Your custom code to unpublish/publish the content goes here.
  }

}
```

Source: "Responding to a flagging", located within the [Flag's community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/305086).

Comment: thanks Pierre,
In First condition What Code I am write Publish/unpublish query or another code